# (Python) Parsing tab delimited strings with newline characters

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file that is tab delimited but fields may contain newline characters and I would like to maintain the field that has newlines.  My current implementation creates new fields from each "\n".

I have tried the csv module and just splitting on "\t" with no success on what I'm looking for.  The following is a sample line from a given file:

*Field_1 \t Field_2 \t Field_3 \n Additional Text \n More text \t Field_4*

I would like to generate a list of 4 elements from the data above.

*["Field_1", "Field_2", "Field3 \n Additional Text \n More text", "Field_4"]*

Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Wait, how do you know the difference between new lines in the file and new lines in the content?  Or are you saying there are literally backslash-n in the file?

Comment: Is field 3 enclosed in quote characters?  View your data file in a text editor to make sure of your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try splitting on the tab like this?

```
data = 'Field_1 \t Field_2 \t Field_3 \n Additional Text \n More text \t Field_4'
print data.split('\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `fileName` with the path to the file you're reading from:

```
inFile = open(fileName, "r")
rawData = inFile.read() # Entire file's contents as one multiline string (if there's a line break)
data = rawData.split("\t")
inFile.close()
```

There is also the option (generally recommended) of using the `with` statement for File I/O:

```
with open(fileName, "r") as inFile:
    rawData = inFile.read() # Entire file's contents as one multiline string (if there's a line break)
    data = rawData.split("\t")
# you can omit the inFile.close() statement.
```

With the `with` statement, the opened file stream will be automatically closed in the event of an error that appears at runtime, but it's less clear to people learning File I/O on how it works.